# Is it possible, in NetSuite, to workflow a button to create a new email with no set recipient

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

currently we have a custom record with a list/record field that links to an opportunity and i can create a button that creates new emails (via workflow) pulling recipient information from the contact on the opportunity record but what i want to know is if there is a way to replicate the "New Email" button usually found on a record's Mail Merge tab as i want to be able to press a button to open an email template that has no recipient set as currently the send email workflow option has both recipient and sender as mandatory fields - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Custom Record Type to check the 'Enable Mail Merge' checkbox, then you should have this functionality.

[image]

If you want the functionality to be available via a button in the main button group, I don't believe this is possible using a workflow only; however you can achieve this with scripting.  To do this, create a User Event script with a Before Load function to add the button to the form, and a Client Script which can be called on clicking the button.  Upload and deploy to the Custom Record Type that you want the email button to appear on.  For this answer I'll assume you have at least a basic knowledge of creating a script record - let me know if you need more information.

The User Event script:

```
function emailButton(type, form)
{
  //add a custom button on the form
  //specify the function name of the Client script created in Step 2

  form.addButton('custpage_Add', 'Start Email','startEmail();');

  //set the internal id of the Client script created in Step 2
  form.setScript('customscript_ppcs_start_email_client'); 

}
```

The Client script:

```
function startEmail() {
    new_message([['transaction',document.forms['main_form'].elements['id'].value],['entity',document.forms['main_form'].elements['companyid'].value],['template',['66']]], 'EMAIL'); 
}
```

You can modify the template used by replacing the '66' with the internal ID of the template you want, or you can remove it.  You can also remove the 'entity' as you don't want the recipient to be set.  Below is an example with both removed:

```
function startEmail() {
    new_message([['transaction',document.forms['main_form'].elements['id'].value]], 'EMAIL'); 
}
```

Comment: We already have that enabled but what i'm trying to do is add the same functionality to a different button to be used elsewhere.

Comment: That looks very promising - i will let you know if it does what i need, thanks.